# How to obtain an ordered autocompletion list for Words, not only words?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I have a text file with tags (preceded by ©) :

```
The Louvre is near the Seine (©Paris, ©Museum)

Pergamon Museum is in Museum Insel (©Berlin, ©Museum)

British Museum is near Russell Square (©London, ©Museum)
```

1) Whenever I want to use Ctrl+N and ©, in order to add a tag, I would like to have :

```
©Paris

©Berlin

©London
```

but instead, I get a list of all the different words of the buffer.

2) Better still, I would like that list to be alphabetically ordered :

```
©Berlin

©London

©Paris
```

Is there a solution to these two complementary questions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

Add character(s) to `iskeyword`, in current buffer or `vimrc`

```
:set iskeyword+=©
```

I don't think there is a pre-defined setting to sort the completion list. Plugins might be there, not sure.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> searches in backward direction (**p**revious matches)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> searches in forward direction (**n**ext matches)

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you very much.